# When $n$ is a power of $2$, is $\mathbb Z[\zeta_n +1/\zeta_n]$ a PID?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

$\mathbb Z[\zeta_n +1/\zeta_n]$ where $n$ is a power of $2$ and $n>64$

Then we already know $\mathbb Z[\zeta_n]$ is not a PID

However, I don't know $\mathbb Z[\zeta_n +1/\zeta_n]$ is a PID.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you define $\zeta_n$? If it is the $n$th root of unity, try computing $1/\zeta_n$. Can you write it as a polynomial in $\zeta_n$?

Comment: @vrugtehagel: I don't see how this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Conjecturally, yes. This is known as the Weber class number problem, and has some partial results. Weber originally proved that the class numbers of such fields are always odd, and Fukuda and Komatsu vastly improved that to show that no prime less than $10^9$ divides the class number and if a prime $p$ does divide the class number then $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{32}$.

The most recent results I am aware of on this question are due to John C. Miller (preprint available [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.1094v1.pdf)), who showed that $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_n + \zeta^{-1}_n)$ has class number 1 when $n = 256$ (and $n = 512$ assuming GRH).

Comment: Oh thanks. when n=1024 does not prove? That's amazing. Thank you very much